# I have two input fields and I don't want to show space between them

Tags: jquery, html, css

These are my two input fields, and when I run the code it shows spaces between them.
Can anyone tell me how to remove the space in between them?
Thank you.

this is my whole code which I am writing if any help can be done please tell me I will appreciate it 
thank you again.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<style>

h6 {
     text-align: center;
   color:   #A7A7AF;
}
h5 {

    color: #A7A7AF;

}
.input {
  display: block;
    width: 100%;
}


.ui-bar-f {
    color: red;
    background-color: #476296;
}

.ui-body-f {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background-color:#476296;
}


.ui-page-theme-f {
    background-color: #EBF0F3;
}
.create {
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
    background-color: #5A9239;
}
.btn1 {
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
    background-color: #476296;
}

</style>
</head>


<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="f">

  <div data-role="header" data-theme="f" class="ui-body-f">
    <h1>facebook</h1>
  </div>


  <h5 style=" margin:0px; color: #8C812F; background-color: #FFFFBE;">You must login first</h5>


<div data-role="main"  class="ui-content"  >
    <h4  style=" text-align: center; color: #476296; background-color: #FFFFBE;">Get Facebook for Android and browse faster</h4>
<h5>Already have an account ?</h5>


        <input type="text"  name="fullname" placeholder="Email" ><input type="text"  id="Password" placeholder="Password" >

         <a href="#"  type="button" style="input: margin: 0;" class="ui-btn btn1 ui-corner-all"   >Log In</a>

          <h5>New to facebook ?</h5>


          <a href="#" type="button"  style="input: margin: 0;" class="ui-btn create ui-corner-all"  >Create New Account</a>

          <h6 >Forget password    Help Centre</h6>
          <h6>Trouble login ?</h6>

</div>





  <div data-role="footer" style=" text-align: center; color: #A7A7AF;">
    <p> <i> <b><font color="#000000">English(US)</font> </b></i>  <font>.Espanol .portugese(Brazil) more..</font>  </p>
    <h3>Facebook©2003</h3>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

[image: you can see the input types are still not joined]

Thank you.

Comment: an input should be<input> not <input></input>... Also you need to show the rest of your code. Maybe a jsfiddle

Comment: @Andrew:: removed the input tag but no luck with that

Comment: What do you mean by space??? Space in the HTML or space on the browser? If its browser space then we need to see the CSS

Comment: Can't you just remove the spaces between them to remove the space between them?...

Comment: Without the associated CSS we can't help. Just setting `display:block` and `width:100%` should be enough - http://jsfiddle.net/970Ldgdy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this...

```
<input type="text"  name="fullname" placeholder="Email" ><!--   
--><input type="text"  id="Password" placeholder="Password" >
```

(notice the HTML comment)

Or this...

```
<input type="text"  name="fullname" placeholder="Email" ><input type="text"  id="Password" placeholder="Password" >
```

Example...

```html
<input type="text"  name="fullname" placeholder="Email" ><!--
--><input type="text"  id="Password" placeholder="Password" >  

<br>

<input type="text"  name="fullname" placeholder="Email" ><input type="text"  id="Password" placeholder="Password" >
```

---

**EDIT**

Inlight of your newly added code, the space is coming from this Jquery mobile CSS...

```
.ui-input-text, .ui-input-search {
  margin: .5em 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

You can remove the space by adding this more specific rule to your own CSS...

```
.ui-content .ui-input-text {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/6xtcc09s/)

Comment: No changes still the same thing

Comment: Look at the example - There is no space

Comment: I have added image with my problem can the space between them can reduce more ?

Comment: You mean the vertical space? Hard to say without seeing your CSS. You probably need to remove the margin ... `input: margin: 0;` Set up a JSFiddle showing the issue

Comment: I have attached my code can you watch it and tell me the errors Thank you

Answer (score -1):

**Horizontally**

```
<input type="text"  name="fullname" placeholder="Email">
<input type="text"  id="Password" placeholder="Password">
```

**Vertically**

```
<input type="text"  name="fullname" placeholder="Email"><br>
<input type="text"  id="Password" placeholder="Password">
```